# Do I really need all these dependencies?

Tags: react-native

I'm new to `react native`, and I notice when I create a new project using `react-native init projectName` that it creates something like 600+ folders in the `node_modules` folder.

I was sort of expecting to be able to create a bare bones project with only essential dependencies and then add new stuff as necessary as I would do in any other language. I don't really know what any of the dependencies are already, and of the half a dozen or so things I've needed so far I've had to install a new dependency and haven't used anything from here except for the essential `react` and `react-native` modules.

Is this how you guys all start your projects, or does this contain hundreds of extras that don't need to be in my project, and if so how do I create a bare bones project? I tried looking at options for the `init` command and saw one called `skip-install` that looked like it would install w/o installing all the dependencies but it seems to have had no effect.

Comment: most of the folders are only for development purposes. behinde the scene a ton of thing happens like: compiling your coder to older version. if you use typescript compiling it to JS. minify, bundling live server etc. etc. .... everything is a own module

Comment: usually you have some command like "npm run build" that builds your production app witch is much smaller

Comment: @Ifaruki If I run into an error in a module and I'm trying to open the file to figure out what's going on, it's not really awesome to have to wade through hundreds of folders to find the one I want. I'd rather it be clean and just have what I need. If these modules are actually required by react then fine... I will just install any addl 3rd party modules to a custom folder. But if not then I'd just as soon remove them. That's what I was trying to ask... are these really required or just installed as part of a template by default. Maybe you answered that, but if so it's not clear to me.

Comment: usually we never touch the node_modules folder. if you dont need some package then you need to remove the package out of your `package.json` under dependendcies. Next time somebody install your packages it will install everything whats added to the package .json

Answer (score 1):

Node Module folder contains all the dependencies of the whole app. You can check this in every folder's Readme.md file. If you add any new library in your package.json, everything will be listed there.
To start with, create-react-app contains

- a compiler (Babel),
- a bundler (Webpack),
- a linter (ESLint),
- a styling pipeline tool (SCSS),
- a development server with live reloading,
- a code minifier,
- a test runner (Jest),

Comment: You reminded me about "create-react-app". I had used "react-native init" to create projects recently having totally forgot about that. So I just tried create-react-app and it is a little cleaner in the root but interestingly it has almost double the number of modules. Crazy. But what I'm trying to figure out is, are these modules actually mostly required by react or are a lot of them just included as part of a template but not really used (unless you specifically reference them in your project)?